# Mega menu drop down hover issue

Tags: jquery, css, hover, megamenu

[Mega menu](http://www.danhumphrey.co.uk/nav/index2.html)

It looks Ok on hover however if you move your cursor down a tiny bit or onto the actual drop down black box the hover disappears. I've hit a bit of a hurdle and need some help.

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<nav>
<ul id="headNav">

    <li id="item1" class="mega">
       <h2> <a href="" class="hover">Item 1</a></h2>
        <div id="item1" class="dropdown gradbackground">Sub-Item 1</div>
    </li>

    <li id="item2" class="mega">
       <h2> <a href="" class="hover">Item 2</a></h2>
        <div id="item2" class="dropdown gradbackground">Sub-Item 2</div> 
    </li>



 </ul>

 <div class="clear"></div>

 </nav>

 </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
a {color:#fff;}
/* Mega Menu*/

ul#headNav 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 16px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #484848; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #484848 0%, #313030 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#484848), color-stop(100%,#313030)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #484848 0%,#313030 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #484848 0%,#313030 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #484848 0%,#313030 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #484848 0%,#313030 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#484848', endColorstr='#313030',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #3B3B3B;
}

ul#headNav li {
height: 39px;
position: relative;
float: left;
padding: 0px 8px;
border-right: 1px solid #565656;

}


ul#headNav li a {
width: 126px;
height: 40px;
position: relative;
top: -10px;
display: block;
line-height: 60px;
text-align: center;
background: url(../img/nav/home.png) no-repeat 0 0;
z-index: 10;
}




ul#headNav li .hover:hover, ul#headNav li a:hover {
height: 60px;
background: #474747;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;

}

ul#headNav li:nth-of-type(8n) {border-right:none;}

li#recording a.hover
{
    line-height: 18px;
    top: 2px;
}


ul#headNav li a {
width: 101px;
background: url(../img/nav/home.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}




a#BuyNow { line-height: 38px;}
a#BuyNow:hover { text-decoration:underline; color:#fff!important;}

#quicksearch 
{
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 44px;
}

nav h2 
{
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-size:13px !important; 
    color:#000000; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0 0px; 
    line-height:28px !important; 
    height:0px;
    }

a.liLink {background:none !important; border:none ;}


    /* End Mega Menu  */ 



.dropdown
{
    display: none;
    width:570px;
    position: absolute;
    top:23px;
    padding:10px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:400px;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow:0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index:99;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:999999;
    border-top:16px solid #474747;
    background:#000;
}

.regtable 
{
    margin:20px 0px 0px 30px;

}


#item1.dropdown {top: 50px; left: 8px; }
#item2.dropdown {left: 8px; top: 50px; }





 ul.megacatlist li ul li,  ul.megabrandlist li ul li
{
    display:block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    float:none !important;
    line-height:16px !important;
    border:none !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0px 0 1px 0 !important;
    text-transform:none !important;
    height:20px;

}

 ul.megacatlist li ul li a,  ul.megabrandlist li ul li a
{
    color: #666666 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px !important;
    padding:1px 5px 0px 5px !important;
    border:none;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    text-transform:none !important;

}

 ul.megacatlist li ul li a:hover, ul.megabrandlist li ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline !important;
    border:none !important;
    }

.topNavSection a{color:#ffffff;}
.topNavSection h3{padding:5px;border:none; text-decoration:underline;}


.dropdown a, .dropdown ul li ul li  {
    color: #4D4D4D;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none !important;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
}


.dropdown a:hover, .dropdown ul li ul li:hover
{
    margin:0px;
    padding-left:5px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    display:block;
    }



#topnav ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown ul li ul {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
#topnav ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 51px;
}

#topnav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 35px 0 0;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}

.dropdown ul li ul li {
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}

.dropdown ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    max-width: 226px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto !important;
    border: medium none !important;
}

.dropdown ul li:nth-of-type(2n) 
{
    margin:0px;
}

/*end mega menu*/
```

**JS**

```
/* start megamenu script */

function slideSubDown() {
    $(".mega").children('.dropdown').slideUp("fast");
    $(this).children('.dropdown').slideDown({
        speed: 1600,
        easing: "swing"
    })
    //$(this).children('a').addClass("pointer");
}
function slideSubUp() {
    $(".mega").children('.dropdown').slideUp("250");
    //$(this).children('a').removeClass("pointer");
}
$(".mega").hoverIntent(slideSubDown, slideSubUp);

/*end megamenu script */
```

Comment: Code for this would be handy to help you out

Answer (score 0):

Work with hover on the entire list item (as opposed to only the h2 tag), this way it includes the dropdown menu and you should get the expected behaviour

Comment: This could be added as a comment since it is not an answer.

Comment: the question as I see it is 'how to fix the issue of the disappearing box'. This is how

Comment: The hover isn't on the h2 tag it's currently on the li and a tag

Answer (score 0):

set hover for `li` element, it may help

Answer (score 0):

take only html (divs only) css and JS from this  http://jsfiddle.net/rUZVT/ , and restyle it As you want/like change classes or change styling etc